# Retrieve <video></video> tags from html string in PHP

Tags: php, html, video, tags

Can somebody help me to retrieve video tag attributes from html in PHP

```
<video height="" width=""><source src=""></source></video>
```

I need to retrieve video attributes (width, height) and src tag from source.. and later remove these video tags from HTML.

Comment: <video height="300" width="300"><source src="/video1.flv"></source</video>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3577641)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [phpquery](https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) for example.

Comment: Not sure..how to use phpquery.. could you please explain in detail. Thanks.